# Thread.sleep not compiling

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I was trying to use `Thread.sleep` for something. I just put it between some `ImageIcon` declarations like so:

```
ImageIcon cheese = new ImageIcon("C:\\ et cetera \\PictureThing.gif");
Thread.sleep(500);
ImageIcon cheese2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\ et cetera \\AnotherPictureThing.gif");
```

and I compiled it and ran.

Just to note, don't worry, the above code wasn't the only code, so don't tell me no duh it didn't work. What it actually did was, once I ran it in the command line, it just said something like "error: unreported exception InterruptException, must be caught or declared to be thrown".

What am I doing wrong, and do I need to add something to it to make `Thread.sleep` work right?

Answer (score 3):

You need to catch the thrown `InterruptedException`. Wrap your call in a `try { }` block

```
try {

    Thread.sleep(500);

}
catch (InterruptedException ex) {

    ex.printStackTrace();

}
```

I'd really suggest reading up on try-catch-blocks and exception handling [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Comment: I actually did read the try-catch-blocks stuff and figured out when and where and how and why to use it and stuff. I'll try that. I dunno why I didn't already catch the error. Maybe it was laziness :P